# logicpuzzle package only produces text instead of pictures

Tags: logicpuzzle

I have been looking at the `logicpuzzle` package with my MikTex installation.

I have tried to use some of the examples from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle/logicpuzzle.pdf)

**puzzle.tex**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{article}

\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{ddsudoku}
            \framepuzzle
            \filldiagonals[orange!50]
            \ddsudokucell{1}{5}{1}
            \ddsudokucell{1}{4}{3}
            \ddsudokucell{2}{3}{4}
            \ddsudokucell{4}{1}{3}
            \ddsudokucell{4}{3}{2}
            \ddsudokucell{5}{4}{4}
        \end{ddsudoku}
        \hspace{1.5cm}
        \begin{ddsudoku}
            \framepuzzle
            \filldiagonals[orange!50]
            \setrow{5}{1,3,4,5,2}
            \setrow{4}{3,2,5,1,4}
            \setrow{3}{5,4,3,2,1}
            \setrow{2}{2,5,1,4,3}
            \setrow{1}{4,1,2,3,5}
        \end{ddsudoku}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, when I try to build a PDF from this source, I get the following error:

`puzzle.tex:7: LaTeX Error: Environment ddsudoku undefined.`

When I compiled my source, I was asked to install the missing packages and confirmed those, so they should be available.

Am I missing anything else in my preamble that is required for this package to work? I have tried using other puzzle examples than `ddsudoku` but they cause the same error (undefined environment).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! I cannot reproduce this issue when compiling your code on my TeXLive2019 installation with pdflatex.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your log file? Maybe you are compiling with `nonstopmode` (which skips over errors)?

Comment: @Marijn, looking at the log file, the first error that I find there is the one I quoted above: `puzzle.tex:7: LaTeX Error: Environment ddsudoku undefined.`

After that, there are a number of `Undefined control sequence` entries, but I suspect these are a consequence of the commands inside the ddsudoku environment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: The bug has been fixed in not even 20 minutes! A MiKTeX update will resolve the issue.

---

[original answer]

This is due to a name clash in the MiKTeX `texmf` tree. There is another package `battleship` that contains a file `logicpuzzle.sty` which shadows the desired package file. It looks to me like this is an older version of today's `logicpuzzle` package (`battleship` contains verion 1.0 from 2013, the current version is 2.5).

I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/102) regarding this with the MiKTeX people.

Since MiKTeX will never look for `logicpuzzle.sty` beyond `battleship`, even when that package is not installed but `logicpuzzle` is, there is currently only one way around it: Create a coopy of `logicpuzzle` that is located before `battleship` on the search path. To do this, do the following (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/48973) for details):

1. Create a directory for your local texmf tree, for example `C:\local_texfm\`.
2. In that directory, create the subdirectory `tex\latex\logicpuzzle` and copy the files from the corresponding folder in your MiKTeX installation directory there.
3. Add the directory to your MiKTeX TEXMF root directories (go to Settings → Directories in the MiKTeX console).
4. Refresh your file name database (in the Tasks menu of the MiKTeX console).

This should make it work.

Note that you will have to update this local version of the package yourself and remove it manually once the MiKTeX bug has been fixed.

Comment: thank you for figuring this out and for reporting the bug. I have manually uninstalled the battleship package, updated my MikTeX installation and now everything works as expected!